# SQL Loop/Crawler

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out some ways to accomplish this script.  I import an excel sheet and then I need to populate 5 different tables based on this excel sheet.  However for this example I just need help with the initial loop then I think I can work through the rest.

```
select distinct Department from IPACS_New_MasterList
where Department is not null
```

This provides me a list of 7 different departments.

```
Dep1, Dep2, Dep3, Dep4, Dep5, Dep6, Dep7
```

For each of these departments I need to perform some code.

Step #1:

Insert the department into `table_one`

I then need to keep the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for the rest of the code.

Step #2

perform the second loop (inserting all functions in that department into `table2`.

I'm not sure how to really do a foreach row in this select statement loop, or if I need to do something completely different.  I've looked at several answers but can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for.

Sample Data:

Source Table

```
Dep1, func1, process1, procedure1
dep1, func1, process1, procedure2
dep1, func1, process2, procedure3
dep1, func1, process2, procedure4
dep1, func1, process2, procedure5
dep1, func2, process3, procedure6
dep2, func3, process4, procedure7
```

My Tables:

My first table is a list of every department from the above query.  With a key on the `departmentID`.  Each department can have many functions.

My second table is a list of all functions with a key on `functionID` and a foreign key on `departmentID`.  Each function must have 1 department and can have many processes

My third table is a list of all processes with a key on `processID` and a foreign key on `functionID`.  Each process must have 1 function and can have many procedures.

Comment: If you're creating multiple tables from one source table, you can use SELECT statements to isolate what bits belong in each table (no looping). Hard to tell from your question how to assist you, some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: So essentially.  The table has department, functions, processes, procedures.  For each department I need to insert into the department table.  For each function attached to the department I need to add to the functions table which had a foreign key to the departments table. @Goat_CO

Comment: @Goat_CO added some sample data.

Comment: SQL is a set based language.  One command operates on some or all of the records in the table. You're thinking procedurally: one record at a time.  Each of the things you're describing above could be done in one or two statements.

Comment: You say you need 5 different tables, is the first table just a list of departments? What's in the 2nd table?  A sample of what you want might clarify.

Comment: @Goat_CO I updated the original post with requested information.  Let me know if I need to add more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can use without a loop.

1) If  you have candidate keys in your source (department name) just join your source table back to the table you inserted

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Department 
(Name)
SELECT DISTINCT Dep1 
FROM SOURCE;

INSERT INTO Functions 
(
   Name,
   DepartmentID)
SELECT DISTINCT
  s.Func1,
  d.DepartmentID
FROM
  source s
  INNER JOIN Department d
  on s.dep1 = d.name;


INSERT INTO
  processes 
(
    name,
    FunctionID,
    [Procedure]
)
SELECT
   s.process1,
   f.FunctionID,
   s.procedure1
FROM
  source s
  INNER JOIN Department d
  on s.dep1 = d.name
  INNER JOIN Functions f 
  on d.DepartmentID = f.departmentID
  and s.func1 = f.name;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/147f2/6)

2) If you don't have candidate keys in your source then you can use the [output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

For example here if a department weren't guaranteed to be unique this would correctly find only the newly add

```
DECLARE @Department TABLE
(
    DepartmentID INT
)


DECLARE @Functions TABLE
(
    FunctionID INT
)



INSERT INTO Department 
(Name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.DepartmentID INTO @Department
SELECT DISTINCT Dep1 
FROM SOURCE



INSERT INTO Functions 
(
   Name,
   DepartmentID)
OUTPUT INSERTED.FunctionID INTO @FunctionID
SELECT DISTINCT
  s.Func1,
  d.DepartmentID
FROM
  source s
  INNER JOIN Department d
  on s.dep1 = d.name
  INNER JOIN @Department d2 
  ON d.departmentID = d2.departmentID;


INSERT INTO
  processes 
(
    name,
    FunctionID,
    [Procedure]
)
SELECT
   s.process1,
   f.FunctionID,
   s.procedure1
FROM
  source s
  INNER JOIN Department d
  on s.dep1 = d.name
  INNER JOIN Functions f 
  on d.DepartmentID = f.departmentID
  and s.func1 = f.name
  INNER JOIN  @Functions f2
  ON f.Functions = f2.Functions

SELECT * FROM Department;
SELECT * FROm Functions;
SELECT * FROM processes;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/147f2/15)

Comment: is a candidate  key the primary key with identity insert turned on?  My department table primary key is departmentID with identity insert on, my functions table primary key is functionId with identity insert turned on, and it has a foreign key for departmentID.

Comment: @conradFrix - Why is a loop frowned upon in SQL?

Comment: @logixologist because it is slower than many other things you can do in SQL.  It's expensive to traverse over data row by row rather than using the result set.  That is all I know, but I just don't know enough about sql to have done this any other way than a loop.

Comment: @logixologist I edited my answer to remove my disposition against loops. That said I find loops more difficult to correctly write. Also they tend to be slower but that's not always a problem or true

Comment: @JamesWilson a candidate key is just another name for a unique key.

Comment: @ConradFrix Thanks, I do have them uniquely identified so I will try out the first option tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks conrad even tho you and @Goat_CO gave very similar answers and both worked, I appreciate you both.  I think I will mark this one as the answer as it contains more info and SQL Fiddle.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding what you are trying to do... yes you can use a loop. Its not really talked about and I bet I am going to get some feedback from other SQL developers that its not a best practice. But if you really need to do a loop

```
DECLARE @rowcount as int
DECLARE @numberOfRows as int
SET @rowcount = 0
SET @numberOfRows = SELECT COUNT(*) from tablename --put in anything to get the number of times to loop.

WHILE @numberOfRows <= @rowcount

BEGIN

--Put whatever process you need to repeat here

SET @rowcount = @rowcount + 1
END
```

Comment: Yeah that was my problem.  I can't see any other way outside of a loop to do what I need to do.  I'm sure there is, I just can't see it yet.

Comment: Ok try it and see if this works for you.... I have had to use it on occasion. For the longest time I didnt even know SQL had a loop like this and I had to use a Cursor which is yucky. Good luck!

Comment: I would recommend wrapping this in a transaction between the BEGIN and END so that if one things fails in your loop it wont mess up your data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have tables set up with an IDENTITY field set for the Primary Key, you can populate each successive table's foreign key by joining to the previous table and the source table, something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT DISTINCT Department
FROM SourceTable
GO

INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT DISTINCT b.Deptartment_ID, a.Function
FROM SourceTable a
JOIN Table1 b
   ON a.Department = b.Department
GO

INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT DISTINCT b.Function_ID, a.Process
FROM SourceTable a
JOIN Table2 b
   ON a.Function = b.Function
GO

INSERT INTO Table4
SELECT DISTINCT b.Process_ID, a.Procedure
FROM SourceTable a
JOIN Table3 b
   ON a.Process = b.Process
GO
```

Comment: I have over 500 individual procedures.  Will this allow me to run the code one time and it does everything for me assigning everything to the correct, department, process, function, procedure?

Comment: Yes, this is assuming the tables are set up with an auto-incremeting ID field in place, and you're only inserting the Value and the Foreign Key value for each entry.

Comment: After you create the first table you could run just the SELECT portion from the next to test the output.

Comment: alright I will work with that, won't have time to test it until tomorrow but I like where it is going. :)

Comment: You can either list out which fields you're inserting ie `INSERT INTO Table2 (Department_ID,Function)`  Or you can just SELECT them in the order they appear in the table, ignoring your auto-identity field.